# println() produces different output

Tags: kotlin, string-interpolation

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  var _array = arrayOf(1 , 2 , 3.14 , 'A', "item" , "a b c d", 4)

  println("$_array[3]")  // [Ljava.lang.Object;@1b6d3586[3]
  println("${_array[3]}") // A
  println(_array[3]) // A

  println( _array[3] + " is _array's item") // ERROR
  println( "" + _array[3] + " is _array's item") // A is _array's item

}
```

I am confused why the code above makes different output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
println("$_array[3]")  // [Ljava.lang.Object;@1b6d3586[3]
```

prints the `_array` object reference followed by `[3]`, you use string interpolation only for the `_array` argument

```
println("${_array[3]}") // A
```

prints the 4th element of `_array`, you use string interpolation for the `_array[3]` argument

```
println(_array[3]) // A
```

prints the 4th element of `_array` (same as above)

```
println( _array[3].toString() + " is _array's item") // ERROR
```

it needs `toString()` to get printed because the elements of `_array` are of type `Any`  and the + sign after it is inconclusive
it prints the 4th element of _array

```
println( "" + _array[3] + " is _array's item") // A is _array's item
```

it does not need `toString()` as it is preceded by an empty string and the + sign is interpreted by the compiler as string concatenation  so it prints the 4th element of `_array`

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it one by one:

```
println("$_array[3]")
```

Same as `println("${_array}[3]")` - [3] is just a string here, not interpolated

```
  println("${_array[3]}")
```

Entire `_array[3]` is interpolated

```
println(_array[3])
```

Same as `println(_array[3].toString())`

```
println( _array[3] + " is _array's item") // ERROR
```

Your array is `Array<Any>`. `plus()` is not defined for (Any,String)

```
println( "" + _array[3] + " is _array's item") // A is _array's item
```

`plus()` is defined for pair (String,Any), and it returns a string

Answer (score 2):

When you use complex expression in string template, you have to wrap it inside curly braces. But that is optional for single variable.

So, this line

```
println("$_array[3]")
```

means same thing as

```
println(_array.toString() + "[3]")
```